# Bootsrap как правильно записать этот код без повторений col-12

Tags: bootstrap

Как отредактировать правильно этот код чтобы постоянно не писать "div class="col-12"? И

```
 <div class="col-12">@Html.Label("Введите имя")</div>
    <div class="col-12">@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Name)</div>
    <div class="col-12">@Html.Label("Введите Email")</div>
    <div class="col-12">@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Email)</div>
    <div class="col-12">@Html.Label("Введите Дату Рождения")</div>
    <div class="col-12">@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.DateOfBirth, new { @type="date" })</div>
    <div class="col-12">@Html.Label("Введите Номер Телефона")</div>
    <div class="col-12">@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Phones)</div>
    <div class="col-12">@Html.Label("Выберите страну")</div>
    <div class="col-12">@Html.Label("Выберите пол")</div>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в стилях по умолчанию задать нужную ширину всем дивам, а когда вам потребуется ширина отличная от заданной -то применяйте нужный col-